# CDK Fargate deploy is adding a "allow anyone" inbound rule to security group

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I'm setting up a Fargate cluster with AWS CDK v2. On deploy, CDK is adding a "0.0.0.0/0 Allow from anyone on port 80" rule to a pre-made security group.  Any idea how to stop this behavior?  Here is my service stanza:

```
 const service = new ecs.FargateService(this, "SBfargate", {
  cluster,
  desiredCount: 1,
  taskDefinition: fargateTaskDefinition,
  assignPublicIp: true,
  securityGroups: [sbsg],
  serviceName: 'SB-Fargate_service',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3177 after more digging. Mutable: false on the SG stanza worked as I wanted.